# Yii2 2.0.31 in Homestead errors

Tags: craft3, yii

I am getting the following error when trying to update Craft from 3.3.18.4 to 3.3.19 and any version after. It seems like Homestead or Vagrant is having some sort of issue with IpValidator or the Class 'Yii'. Anyone else seen this issue before?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Yii' not found in /home/vagrant/****/****/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/validators/IpValidator.php on line 218

Error: Class 'Yii' not found in /home/vagrant/****/****/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/validators/IpValidator.php on line 218
```

Comment: Can you set your `craftcms/cms` to `3.3.19` in your compser.json file, then run `composer update` from your project's root and try again?

Comment: Have tried that already. Still the same error. It was able to get it working when using MAMP but not Homestead.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the same issue when upgrading 3.3.15 to any other version, running with docker.